# A question about the eigenvector and the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $(1, 0, 0)^T$ and $(0, -1, 1)^T$ be eigenvector of a 3x3 matrix $A$ with eigenvalue 1 and $(-2, -2, 1)^T$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue 2.Put $e_3=(0, 0, 1)^T$.

Find eigenvector $v$ and $w$ of $A$ s.t. $v+w=e_3$.

The above is the HW that the solution is using $Ax=e_3$ to prove $e_3$ is the span of these 3 eigenvector and then find $v,w$.

Can anyone tell what it really done in solving this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T, v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$, and $w =  \begin{bmatrix} -2 & -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$.

Find coefficients $c_1,c_2$ and $c_3$ such that $c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 w = e_3$.  Then let $v = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2$ and you are done.

Comment: so if  v1 , v2 is the eigenvector, span(v1,v2) is also the eigenvector ?

Comment: Yeah, that's right, if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue $\lambda$, then any linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is also an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.